# How to keep values of other column as it is in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

This is my code !!!

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b': [100,1,2,4,6,-55], 'a': ['a','b','c','d','e','f']})
df2=df2.sort_values(by='b',ascending=1)
df2.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(df2.index))
# Computing IQR
Q1 = df2['b'].quantile(0.25)
Q3 = df2['b'].quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
#filtering values
filtered = df2.query('(@Q1 - 1.5 * @IQR) <= @df2 <= (@Q3 + 1.5 * @IQR)')
filtered.dropna()
```

my output is this

```
In [162]: filtered
Out[162]: 
     a    b
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  2.0
3  NaN  4.0
4  NaN  6.0
5  NaN  NaN
```

i want output like this

```
In [162]: filtered
Out[162]: 
     a    b

1  b    1.0
2  c    2.0
3  d    4.0
4  e    6.0
```

can anyone please help me to get output like this !! there is some problem with filtered , can anyone help me in that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need change `@df2` to `b` for column `b`:

```
filtered = df2.query('(@Q1 - 1.5 * @IQR) <= b <= (@Q3 + 1.5 * @IQR)')
#if want remove NaNs rows
filtered = filtered.dropna()
print (filtered)
   a  b
1  b  1
2  c  2
3  d  4
4  e  6
```